# What is the Fourier Transform integral equation for a 1D signal and how can it be expanded into 2D, 3D, and 4D?

Tags: signal-analysis, fourier-transform, 3d, 2d, 1d

I know that [image: 1D Fourier Transform]
is the 1D Fourier Transform (FT), and the 2D FT is [image: 2D FT] and 3D FT is [image: 3D FT], but I am not sure whether these expressions are in fact Fourier transform integral equations for a 1D signal, expanded into 2D and 3D. If they are, then I assume 4D would just be $$ G(u,v,w,\omega) = g(x,y,z,t)e^{-i2\pi \cdot (xu+yv+wz+\omega t)}dxdydzdt$$

Please help clarify the above. Thank you. I'm new to signal processing.

Comment: If the limits of integration are $-\infty$ to $\infty$, then yes they are, in Cartesian coordinates.

Comment: Yes those are the limits @Andy Walls. Is it possible to show the expansion into higher dimensions (from 1D to 2, 3, to 4) or is this not something that can be derived from 1D, you simply add the term like I showed? Silly question probably, It's just been a while since I did this kind of math.

Comment: I don't think so.  I mean it's just the 1D definition  applied to each dimension independently.  What is of more concern is the conditions for the existence of the transform for a given $g()$.

Comment: What do you mean? Please explain. @AndyWalls

Comment: Welcome LiuXiu.  We got $\LaTeX$ goin' on here.  You can make nice looking equations and it might be easier than copying bitmaps of equations and pasting them in here.  The other cool thing is that, to answer your question, it helps us if we can copy your $\LaTeX$ equation and paste it and modify it in our answers.

Comment: Thanks, will keep in mind for next time about the Latex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to the DSP stack exchange! For the future, please type out all of your equations using $\LaTeX$ !

As to your question, I will do my best to answer, but I'm not sure if I fully understand your question. But, yes, these are exact expressions for the multi-dimensional extensions of the 1D Fourier transform. For an $N$-D Fourier transform, there needs to be $N$ data domain variables, or dimensions, and $N$ Fourier domain variables/dimensions.

If, for example, you wanted to apply a 1D transform to 2D data you would have something like

$$ G(u,y) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}g(x,y)e^{-j2\pi(xu)}dx $$

If you wanted to apply a 2D transform to 1D data, for example, you would get

$$ G(u,v) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}g(x)e^{-j2\pi(xu+yv)}dxdy $$

In this case, in the $y$ direction, $g(x)$ is treated as a delta function, so $G(u,v)$ along the $v$ dimension would be a constant.

So, to answer what I think is your question, yes, the equations you provided are the exact equations for the multi-dimensional Fourier transforms.

Comment: I've always thunked that the 2D Fourier Transform is:

$$ G(u,v) = \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} g(x,y) \, e^{-j2\pi(xu+yv)} \ \mathrm{d}x \, \mathrm{d}y $$

Comment: It is! I was just giving examples because the original question wasn't the clearest on what  was being asked. I should probably edit my second equation to be $g(u,0)$. By the way, how'd you do the fancy Latex symbol?

Comment: Press the edit button or hit that "edited 39 mins ago" above my pic.

Comment: Thank you everyone.